# Get values from ng-repeater

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to get the id value from each row in a ng-repeater into an input type="text" to be able to save the sort order of the table. But I don't know how to just extract the id, so I get the full vlaue of the list.

The table looks like this:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="position"></th>
        <th>Specification Title</th>
        <th>Last modified</th>
        <th class="right">Used in</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody ui-sortable="sortableOptions" ng-model="specsList">
    <tr ng-repeat="spec in specsList">
        <td class="position draggable"></td>
        <td><a href="#/editSpec/{{spec.id}}">{{spec.title}}</a></td>
        <td>{{spec.lastModified}}</td>
        <td class="right color_green"><strong>{{spec.usedIn}}</strong> of 12 products</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

And the input:

```
<input type="text" id="tableSortOrder" value="{{specsList}}">
```

Current value in the input text:

**[{"id":"123","title":"Brand","lastModified":"2012-08-14","usedIn":"7"},{"id":"789","title":"Amount","lastModified":"2010-07-22","usedIn":"5"},{"id":"456","title":"ISBN","lastModified":"2010-02-24","usedIn":"2"}]**

What I want to achieve:

**123, 789, 456**

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you want one string containing the comma-separated ids?  And you want that inside a text input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?:

```
<input type="text" id="tableSortOrder" value="{{ specsList.map(function(item){return item.id;}).join() }}" />
```

You could do that in a filter too, like this:

```
<input type="text" id="tableSortOrder" value="{{ specsList | splitIds }}" />

app.filter('splitIds', function() {
  return function(ArrayWithIds) {
      return ArrayWithIds.map(function(item){return item.id;}).join();
  };
});
```

I've made this jsfiddle so that you can see how it works: http://jsfiddle.net/d5ye9mus/2/

Comment: This time you beat me to it. +1

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is exactly what I want. I am using the app.filter version. I get the string with comma separated ids, but locally I also get this error in the console. Any ideas?

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$interpolate/interr?p0=%7B%7BspecsList%20%7C%20splitIds%7D%7D&p1=TypeError:%20Cannot%20read%20property%20%27map%27%20of%20undefined

Comment: @user2750754 try using the filter. You can see an example on how to use it here http://jsfiddle.net/d5ye9mus/2/ and as you can see there are no console errors in that example

Comment: I am using the filter, and I noticed that there were no errors in the fiddle. The only difference in my local version in that i am writing app.filter - like this: http://jsfiddle.net/d5ye9mus/5/

But I am also getting the data to the ng-repeater with $http.get - could that affect in any way?

Comment: @user2750754 writing the filter like this "app.filter" won't make any difference. I don't know whether getting the data from $http.get could be an issue, I would have to see the code. But in any event, it's clear that this answer solves the original question, so please accept it. If you have another issue, start a new question and I will help you there. Thanks!

Comment: started a new question. Greatful for any help!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25760629/error-using-filter-on-values-from-http-get/25760726

Comment: @user2750754 I will have a look at it in a few hours, during my launch break