# Error using filter on values from $http.get

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I am using a filter to extract the id's from a repeater. It all works well but in the console I am getting the following error:

```
https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$interpolate/interr?p0=%7B%7BspecsList%20%7C%20splitIds%7D%7D&p1=TypeError:%20Cannot%20read%20property%20%27map%27%20of%20undefined
```

If I replace the **`$http.get`** with static values for *specsList*, there is no error. Any idea on how to get around it in a good way?

JS:

```
app.controller('SpecsController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(event) {
      $http.get('getSpecs.aspx')
          .then(function(result) {
            $scope.specsList = result.data.specs;
          })
          .catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
          });
    });

    $scope.sortableOptions = {
        handle: "> .position",
        helper: function (e, ui) {
              var originals = ui.children();
              var clonedHelper = ui.clone();
              clonedHelper.children().each(function(index) {
                 //$(this).width($(this).width());
                 $(this).width(originals.eq(index).outerWidth());
                 $(this).addClass("dragging");
                 $(this).parent().addClass("dragging_tr");
              });
              return clonedHelper;
        },
        update: function(e, ui) {
            //console.log("update");
        },
        stop: function(e, ui) {
            //Save sortorder
        }
    };
});

app.filter('splitIds', function() {
  return function(ArrayWithIds) {
      return ArrayWithIds.map(function(item){return item.id;}).join();
  };
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" value="{{specsList | splitIds}}" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this should fix your problem:

```
app.filter('splitIds', function() {
  return function(ArrayWithIds) {          
      return (angular.isUndefined(ArrayWithIds) || !angular.isArray(ArrayWithIds))?
                "":
                ArrayWithIds.map(function(item){return item.id;}).join();
  };
});
```

What is happening is that the first time that the filter `splitIds` is called `$scope.specsList` doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 0):

Since a promise is being returned, you need to change `$http.get('getSpecs.aspx')` to `return $http.get('getSpecs.aspx')`

Comment: `$http.get()` call is in an event callback, so how it can be returned? Please explain.

Comment: I still get the error with return $http.get('getSpecs.aspx')